# What Is A Headered Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Headered Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1.2}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Headered }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words }^™\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2017.02.04}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  A*              }&\text{        AN              }\\ \hline
\text{  ADDLE           }&\text{        ADDLED          }\\ \hline
\text{  ADORE           }&\text{        ADORABLE        }\\ \hline
\text{  ADULT           }&\text{        ADOLESCENT      }\\ \hline
\text{  BABY            }&\text{        CHILD           }\\ \hline
\text{  BE*             }&\text{        BEE             }\\ \hline
\text{  BLEMISH         }&\text{        BLISTER         }\\ \hline
\text{  BOA             }&\text{        BOW             }\\ \hline
\text{  BREATHE         }&\text{        BREATH          }\\ \hline
\text{  CANDLES         }&\text{        CANDLE          }\\ \hline
\text{  DIFFERENT       }&\text{        DIFFER          }\\ \hline
\text{  EVERY*          }&\text{        EACH            }\\ \hline
\text{  FAVORABLENESS   }&\text{        FAVOR           }\\ \hline
\text{  FAVOURABLENESS  }&\text{        FLAVOUR         }\\ \hline
\text{  FRIEND*         }&\text{        FIEND           }\\ \hline
\text{  HEADERED*       }&\text{        HEADER          }\\ \hline
\text{  ILLEGIBLE*      }&\text{        LEGIBLE         }\\ \hline
\text{  MISCLASSIFIED*  }&\text{        MAYBE           }\\ \hline
\text{  MULTISYLLABIC*  }&\text{        MULTIPLE        }\\ \hline
\text{  MEASURABILITY*  }&\text{        MEASURED        }\\ \hline
\text{  PRESUPPOSITIONAL*}&\text{        PARTITIONS      }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
<sup>***Single-Headered Words**</sup>

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Headered Words™,Not Headered Words™
A,AN
ADDLE,ADDLED
ADORE,ADORABLE
ADULT,ADOLESCENT
BABY,CHILD
BE,BEE
BLEMISH,BLISTER
BOA,BOW
BREATHE,BREATH
CANDLES,CANDLE
DIFFERENT,DIFFER
EVERY,EACH
FAVORABLENESS,FAVOR
FAVOURABLENESS,FLAVOUR
FRIEND,FIEND
HEADERED,HEADER
ILLEGIBLE,LEGIBLE
MISCLASSIFIED,MAYBE
MULTISYLLABIC,MULTIPLE
MEASURABILITY,MEASURED
PRESUPPOSITIONAL,PARTITIONS
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Headered Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Headered Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

Bonus Headered Word™, which is ***maybe*** the longest Headered Word™:

> ```
> FLOCCINAUCINIHILIPILIFICATION
> ```

---

#### Update 08/11

Marked Single-Headered Words™

#### 2nd<sup>**</sup> Hint 08/18

<sup><sup>**the Single-Headered Words™ didn't count as a hint</sup></sup>
 As a consequence of the property of Headered Words™, they also have the following property:

> Concatenating two Headered Words™ will make a Headered Word™, assuming the result is a word.
>  e.g. BEFRIEND is a Headered Word™ because both BE and FRIEND are Headered Words™.
>
>  This does not necessarily mean that removing a Headered Word™ from a longer Headered Word™ will result in a second short Headered Word™.

Comment: The quoted Not Headered Word™ - 'MAYBE' is not a single word ! It is made up of two words - MAY and BE. In that way ....is it an exception ?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay _Maybe_ and _may be_ are two different, while similar, things. _Maybe_ is a synonym of possibly as an adverb and means "a small chance" as a noun. _May be_ is an adverb and verb, which gives the same meaning as "possibly is/are".

Comment: Does every word/letter can be classified as headered or non-headered? What about KNOW?

Comment: @NikhilBhavar Yes, ever word classifies as a Headered Word™ or a Non-Headered Word™. *KNOW* is a Non-Headered Word™.

Comment: Is the order of letters relevant in a Headered Word™?

Comment: @EJacobs To a certain extent, yes. An anagram of a Headered Word™ will not necessarily be a Headered Word™. For example, ADDER **is** one. Its anagram, DREAD, **is not** one, but another of its anagrams, ADRED, **is** one.

Comment: Would one additional hint be possible? I keep coming back to look at this but I just can't work it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Headered Word™ is a word that...

> when starting from the first letter of the word, jump forward a number of spaces equal to that letters position in the alphabet, then repeat that for each letter you land on, eventually landing *exactly* on the space after the last letter of the word.

And a Single-Headered Word™ is one that...

> will cause you to jump from the very first letter to after the last letter (i.e. the position of the first letter in the alphabet is equal to the length of the word).

I'm guessing it's called a Headered Word™ because...

> it's similar to a [block of header information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)) in a data file. Blocks of header data often contain within them information on their own size (in bytes/characters), which allows you to easily skip over them and on to the next block of information without reading unnecessary data.
>
>  A Headered Word™ is similar in that it contains within it the means to skip ahead to just past its end. For example, let's say you have a file that contains a series of space-separated Headered Words™:
>
> ```
> A ADDLE ADORE ADULT BABY ...
> ```
>
> If I asked you to read the fifth word from the file, you might take the simple approach of just reading every character sequentially, keeping track of the number of spaces read until you reached 4, then reading the ensuing characters into a string until the next space. You would end up reading every character up to and including the fifth word.
>
>  However, if you knew that all the words in the file were Headered Words™ then you could do this more efficiently. When you read a given character you can skip forward by a number of characters equal to its 0-based position in the alphabet (or do nothing if it's a space), reducing the number of read operations you have to do by skipping many of the characters you're not interested in. Just as an example, here's a simple MATLAB script that would do this (without end-of-file error-checking and such):
>
> ```
> N = 5;  % The word you want
> fid = fopen(wordFile, 'rt');
>
> % Skip unwanted words:
> while (N > 1)
>   newChar = fscanf(fid, '%c', 1);
>   if isspace(newChar)
>     N = N - 1;  % Decrement for each space found
>   else
>     fseek(fid, upper(newChar)-65, 0);  % Skip forward
>   end
> end
>
> % Read the desired word:
> str = '';
> newChar = fscanf(fid, '%c', 1);
> while ~isspace(newChar)
>   str = [str newChar];
>   newChar = fscanf(fid, '%c', 1);
> end
>
> fclose(fid);
> ```

Comment: The explanation for the property and name are correct. The only other thing hidden in the puzzle was a hint in the non-words when starting after maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess

> All of the Headered Words can be combined with 'HEAD' somewhere (either in the beginning or at the end or in between) to form other meaningful words such as A + HEAD = AHEAD, ADDLE + HEAD = ADDLEHEAD, BE + HEAD = BEHEAD etc.

Hold on!

> Others seem to follow a different format ... to explore

Which is

> Not the case with the Non Headerd words !

Comment: An interesting idea that I hadn't thought of while looking for things to make counter-examples for. Fortunately, the longer words and bonus word exclude this. To give a direct counter-example: *BEER* is *not* a Headered Word™.